# how do i find a character in a text and then copy the word that had that character python

Tags: python, string, filter

i want to extract a word out of a string based on what character it got, for Example:

> string: I WANT TO EAT cheese in zeven11

> Extract all words with 11 in it

> extracted: Zeven11

i try find() method but then i only get a on number of the word

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Jut loop it after *split* the string and check/extract.

Comment: but than i can cut the word in half, like Even11 but i wanted Zeven11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
for word in string.split():
    if '11' in word: print(word.capitalize())  # first letter?
```

Comment: i dont know how this works, but it works. Thank you

Comment: It's first *split* to break the string into words, then loop/search.  Which part you don't get it?    Yes, you've to *split* to pieces -(words) first.

Comment: i get it now, i first thought it search for that spesific character, that is why i thought it would split the word in half. Thank you for the explanation